# Javascript reload 2 standalone instances of application simultaneously

Tags: javascript

I'm developing an application that will be shown on two televisions. They will be side by side and will have a auto refresh that actually is set this way:

```
$(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            //mycode
        });
    }, 120000);
});
```

The application will update every 2 minutes on both TVs and of course the user wont be able to launch both of them at same time. So if the application 1 lauches at 12:08:20 and the other instance lauches at 12:09:35, they will be out of synchrony on the update, confusing the user. So I need them to be update simultaneously.

Considering that I have those instances running as a contingency of each other, I can't make a dependency between them.

Its a web application so will be stored at the same server, so I think that there are some ways to do it but I cant come to a reasonable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you could synchronize to a global, universal time that both applications share, instead of session-dependent time. Like, even minute, UTC?

Comment: related questions: [Synchronizing Website (DOM) on multiple devices](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23410892/1048572), [how to synchronize display of multiple android devices?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19976554/1048572)

Comment: I think I can remember a browser demo that did synchronize multiple screens with each other by opening WebRTC P2P-connections, but I can't find a link.

Comment: @ChaseMoskal Don't need to go so far since the application will be running into the same server. I can make any logic related to the server time

Comment: some javascript frameworks provide this as a feature, the question is whether you want to invest on the framework or invest time to build your own solution. http://meteor.com and http://derbyjs.com

Comment: @Bergi Do I need to go too far ? I had some ideas like:  Only make the  interval happen on round odd minutes. What do you think ? I have no idea how to code it but as an idea I could start with.

Comment: Depends on how well you need them synchronized. Of course, up to 2 minutes offset is too much, but how precise do you need it? Notice that the system times of the two TVs might be out of sync as well (not much, but it might matter)

Comment: @Bergi even out of sync, is possible to get server time, right ? this way, even with different times, I would get the same timeframe

Comment: @Dan-SP: With more or less different network latency. But yes, this generally should work.